# Translate a list of multiple words into a list of multiple numbers using a dictionary in Python(2.7.1)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, translate

I have a code `"aaabbbcccdddeee"` that I split up into 3 letter words (such as `'aaa'`,`'bbb'`,`'ccc'` . . . and so on) and assigned a number value to them using `d=dict(zip(('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee'),(123,234,345,456,567)))`

If I have a random sequence of 3 letter words

```
RANDOM="'aaa','bbb','ddd','ccc','eee','ddd','bbb','aaa','eee','ccc'"
```

How can I create a list that converts the RANDOM list into a list composed of the number values that were assigned previously in the dictionary

Example: `RANDOM="'aaa','bbb','ddd','ccc','eee','ddd','bbb','aaa','eee','ccc'"`' to produce `'123','234','456','345','567','456','234','123','567','345'`

I found out how to do it for 1 value:

```
>>> x=d['aaa']

>>> print x

>>> 123
```

How do I do it for the whole list of RANDOM?
It does not work if i simply put:

```
>>> y=d['aaa','bbb','ddd','ccc',...]
```

Does anyone know why this won't work or how to get it to work to get the full list of numbers . i.e. 123,234,456,345,...?

I have been messing with this on and off for a few weeks. It's not homework if your wondering, but this can help me with my studies in other areas.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

y=d['aaa','bbb','ddd','ccc',...]
won't work because 'aaa','bbb','ddd','ccc' is not a valid key. The y = d[ ... ] looks up a SINGLE key value, and returns the SINGLE matching entry for that key in the dictionary.

So, you just need to translate each entry one at a time.

> y=d['aaa']
>
> x=d['bbb']
>
> z=d['ccc']
>
> and then a = [y, x, z] ... etc.

or, being more intelligent, we can use a loop that loops based on the length of the RANDOM list.

> a = list()
>
> for x in RANDOM:
>
> > a.append(d[x])

or, to be fancy

> a = [d[x] for x in RANDOM]

Comment: ah the for loop that makes sense. For some reason its not working, I inputed the statement and received

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 2
    a.append(d[x])
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: `RANDOM` can't actually be used directly, since it's the source string.

Comment: This may be because your RANDOM is currently defined as a string with commas and "'"'s.  Try RANDOM.strip("'").split(",") to make it into a list first.

Comment: >>> random='aaa','bbb','ddd','ccc','eee','ddd','bbb','aaa','eee','ccc'
>>> print random
('aaa', 'bbb', 'ddd', 'ccc', 'eee', 'ddd', 'bbb', 'aaa', 'eee', 'ccc')
>>> a=[d[x] for x in random]
>>> print a
[123, 234, 456, 345, 567, 456, 234, 123, 567, 345]
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Iterate.

```
y = [d[x] for x in L]
```

Comment: One word. All there is to say. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
y = map(d.get, RANDOM)
```

Example:

```
>>> d = dict(zip(('aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee'), (123,234,345,456,567)))
>>> RANDOM = ['aaa','bbb','ddd','ccc','eee','ddd','bbb','aaa','eee','ccc']
>>> y = map(d.get, RANDOM)
>>> y
[123, 234, 456, 345, 567, 456, 234, 123, 567, 345]
```

if `RANDOM` contains an item that is not in `d` then `d.get()` returns `None` instead of raising `KeyError` in the middle of constructing the `y` list.